# unreal engine 4.18.0, Vs2017, Error pointer to incomplete class type is not allowed

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I'm new to C++, and newer still to Unreal Engine 4. I'm following a tutorial to simply rotate an object created with c++. The video appears to be somewhat out of date, being six months old. On one line I get an error with the line `this->SampleMesh->AttachtoComponent(this->RootComponent);` stating `pointer to incomplete class type is not allowed`. I've searched for ways around it, but have had no luck so far.  If anyone knows the updated way to do this, or even a place to find up to date tutorials, I would be grateful. Thanks.

Pickup.cpp

```
#include "Pickup.h"

// Sets default values
APickup::APickup()
{
// Set this actor to call Tick() every frame.  You can turn this off to improve performance if you don't need it.
PrimaryActorTick.bCanEverTick = true;

SampleMesh = CreateDefaultSubobject<UStaticMeshComponent>(TEXT("SampleMesh"));

this->SceneComponent = CreateDefaultSubobject<USceneComponent>(TEXT("SceneComponent"));

this->RootComponent = SceneComponent;

this->SampleMesh->AttachtoComponent(this->RootComponent);

//this->SampleMesh->AttachToComponent(RootComponent, FAttachmentTransformRules::KeepRelativeTransform);

//this->SampleMesh->AttachtoComponent(this->RootComponent, FAttachmentTransformRules::SnapToTargetNotIncludingScale);

//this->SampleMesh->AttachtoComponent(this->SceneComponent);



this->RotationRate = FRotator(0.0f, 180.0f, 0.0f);

this->Speed = 1.0f;
}

// Called when the game starts or when spawned
void APickup::BeginPlay()
{
Super::BeginPlay();

}

// Called every frame
void APickup::Tick(float DeltaTime)
{
Super::Tick(DeltaTime);

this->AddActorLocalRotation(this->RotationRate * DeltaTime * Speed);
}
```

Pickup.h

```
#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "GameFramework/Actor.h"
#include "Pickup.generated.h"

UCLASS()
class LEARNAGAIN_API APickup : public AActor
{
GENERATED_BODY()

public: 
// Sets default values for this actor's properties
APickup();

protected:
// Called when the game starts or when spawned
virtual void BeginPlay() override;

public: 
// Called every frame
virtual void Tick(float DeltaTime) override;

UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BluePrintReadWrite, Category = Pickup)
UStaticMeshComponent* SampleMesh;

UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BluePrintReadWrite, Category = Pickup)
FRotator RotationRate;

UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BluePrintReadWrite, Category = Pickup)
USceneComponent* SceneComponent;

UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, BluePrintReadWrite, Category = Pickup)
float Speed;

};
```

Answer (score 2):

I was stuck on the same issue. Unreal has changed how header files are included.

Add the following included to Pickup.cpp:

```
#include "Classes/Components/StaticMeshComponent.h"
```

and in this specific case you can use the `SetupAttachment` function rather than `AttachToComponent`

More detailed answer [here](https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/670373/pointer-to-incomplete-class-type-is-not-allowed-2.html). Check [this reference guide](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Programming/UnrealBuildSystem/IWYUReferenceGuide/) about the changes. Info on [SetupAttachment](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/API/Runtime/Engine/Components/USceneComponent/SetupAttachment/).